# Why does membersWithRoles not return all members of an organization?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

Using GraphQL for GitHub, I cannot get the full set of members in an organization.

Using this GraphQL query, I get 45 users:

```
query 
{node(id: "#@#@#$@#$##$#@")  { ... on Organization {
     membersWithRole (first: 100) { totalCount nodes { login id name createdAt, updatedAt}
      }}}}
```

and same with this one:

```
 organization(login: "OrgName") {
    membersWithRole(first:100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
        login
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I go to People on the org, I see 54 users. How can I get all users/members in an org?

A few of the users that do not show up as `membersWithRoles` are working fine and pushing/pulling all day long.

The organization is not public.